# How to debug flutter web app to check maximum memory consumption issue?

Tags: flutter, web, memory-management, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing demo trading platform. For data I am dependent on a single **Websocket** and for routing I am using 2 **Nested routers** to display left and right section of the web application.

Issue is If I left my tab open for couple of minutes chrome consumes 300mb-400mb, which cause lags in web application. Need guidance in debugging this memory issue. Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried following approach,

- debugging with chrome dev tools(data is in obfuscated manner)

Flutter web app configuration details,

- version - 3.19
- renderer - HTML

Comment: Did you tried canvaskit web-renderer?

Comment: @DharamBudh can u tell how it will help from memory perspective. I have already tried it.

Comment: Yeah. So basically, we can render the first as an "HTML renderer" and the other as a "canvas-kit renderer". HTML renderer is an old renderer which is not performing well (not smooth and stable). Canvas-kit renderer is smooth and stable and performs well when opening the Flutter web app on our phone.

Comment: From a memory perspective, the HTML renderer is a memory hog (you can see in developer tools) & Canvas-kit handles memory management well (in the past, I converted my flutter web project from HTML to canvas-kit).

Comment: Thank you @DharamBudh. I will try implementing same.